# Rails Insert Has_Many to Has_Many on table with extra field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

We have a simple app, we created these models:

```
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :hardware
end
```

and

```
class Hardware < ApplicationRecord
    has_and_belongs_to_many :clientes
end
```

We created an intermediate table called "clientes_hardwares", when we assign the hardware with the client, we wanna set another field on the table called "vigencia", table:

[image]

On our controller we set:

```
def sethardware
    @cliente = Cliente.find(params[:cliente_id])
    @cliente.hardware << Hardware.find(params[:hardware_id])

    @cliente.hardware.build(:vigencia => "2018-01-01")
    if @cliente.save
        flash[:info] = 'Cliente creado correctamente'
        redirect_to action: 'show', id: params[:cliente_id]
    else
        flash[:alert] = 'Error al crear el usuario'
        redirect_to action: 'show', id: params[:cliente_id]
    end
end
```

Without this line:

```
@cliente.hardware.build(:vigencia => "2018-01-01")
```

It works and set the client_id and the hardware_id, how can we set the extra field called "vigencia", because if we called like build and like param it shows that hardware hasn't that attribute?

Regards

Comment: What you need is a `has_many through:` relationship https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: But i dont have any model for the table with the relations, why should i use through?

Comment: Check this part of the associations guide https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many `You should use has_many :through if you need validations, callbacks or extra attributes on the join model.`. Since you need extra attributes you have to use it instead of a simple HABTM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add attributes to the join table (clientes_hardwares)  the << approach (without explicitly using the join table) will not work as it does not set any additional attribute (Note that the additional attributes are not in clientes or hardwares but in the join table). You must define and use the join model instead:

```
class Cliente < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :clientes_hardwares
  has_many :hardwares through: :clientes_hardwares
end

class Hardware < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :clientes_hardwares
  has_many :clientes through: :clientes_hardwares
end

class ClientesHardware < ApplicationRecord
  belongs to :cliente
  belongs to :hardware
end

def sethardware
  @cliente = Cliente.find(params[:cliente_id])
  @hardware = Hardware.find(params[:hardware_id])

  @cliente.clientes_hardwares.build(
    :hardware => @hardware, 
    :vigencia => "2018-01-01"
  )
  if @cliente.save
    flash[:info] = 'Cliente creado correctamente'
    redirect_to action: 'show', id: params[:cliente_id]
  else
    flash[:alert] = 'Error al crear el usuario'
    redirect_to action: 'show', id: params[:cliente_id]
  end
end
```

Comment: I got "uninitialized constant Cliente::ClientesHardware" with the controller:

   @cliente = Cliente.find(params[:cliente_id])
        @cliente.clientes_hardwares.build(
            :hardware => Hardware.find(params[:hardware_id]), 
            :vigencia => "2018-01-01"
        )

Comment: sorry i change the model

Comment: Have you created the model `ClientesHardware` in a file `clientes_hardware.rb`?